# Border radius and the wonderful cross browser issues - simple fix?

Tags: html, css

I'm, putting a border radius around an image and around a div.  I'm only testing in Safari and Firefox at the moment.  Both yield different results.

For the image I have:

```
margin:0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 6px;

border-radius: 46px;
-webkit-border-radius: 46px;
-moz-border-radius: 46px;
```

Result in Firefox - Beautiful.  Safari - the left side radius is not smooth, looks like the corner has been chopped off a little bit.

For the Div I have:

```
border-right-style: groove;
border-right-color: #eee;
border-right-width: 6px;

border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;

border-top-right-radius: 46px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
```

Result in Safari - Beautiful.  Firefox - the bottom corner radius doesn't display. THe top one does.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Is there a fix or a way of solving this type of issue?

EDIT:  I've updated the order in which they are specified as per http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/ but still the same result

Comment: maybe a full example could explain and show your problem.(html + full css applied to each elements)

Answer (score 1):

to have smoother borders in safari , you should fake your borders with box-shadow or add a thin box-shadow.
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/jbxDo

unprefixed border-radius, in my own opinion, should be last rule.
If four corners have same radius value, the short way to write it should be used too :) ?

Older version of safari/chrome had bugs with image.

Comment: in addition to the border?  I've smoothed it out a great deal by reducing the border width to 1 px instead of 6

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have specified overflow: hidden on the divs with border radius

Comment: Just added but same result for firefox, bottom border radius not showing